# Authenticating Custom url with Devise without having actual controller/action (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise gem in my application and it work fine.

I use omniauth to authenticate Twitter users, and when user types in `http://www.mydomain.com/addtwitter` user will be redirected to Twitter authentication page.

In devise gem, by default when user loads the page `/auth/twitter` it takes user to authorization page. So to customize this i added below code in my `routes.rb` file.

`match "/addtwitter" => redirect("/auth/twitter")`

But i would like to make the `/addtwitter` functionality only to the logged in user.

How do i achieve this without actually creating a controller/action in rails?

is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In devise, you can specify routes that only apply to logged in users.

```
authenticated :user do
  match "/addtwitter" => redirect("/auth/twitter")
end
```